# Applying vtkWarpLens to Camera vs. Scene Data

Tags: c#, vtk

Can anyone help me with vtkWarpLens?

What I am trying to do is implement a distortion pattern on the camera to modify how the data is seen.

Here is the meat of the code (it's in C#, I'm using Activis)

```
        vtkPolyData pd = vtkPolyData.New();

        CreateFromFile(pd); // this creates a triangle representation of a height field

        double [] sr = pd.GetScalarRange();

        vtkLookupTable lut = vtkLookupTable.New();
        lut.SetNumberOfColors(16);
        lut.SetHueRange(0.667, 0.0);
        lut.Build();

        wl = vtkWarpLens.New();
        wl.SetInputConnection(pd.GetProducerPort());
        wl.SetPrincipalPoint(0.5, 0.5);
        wl.SetFormatWidth(1);
        wl.SetFormatHeight(1);
        wl.SetImageWidth(1000);
        wl.SetImageHeight(1000);
        wl.SetK1(0.01307);
        wl.SetK2(0.0003102);
        wl.SetP1(1.953e-005);
        wl.SetP2(-9.655e-005);


        vtkDataSetMapper dsmDistorted = vtkDataSetMapper.New();
        dsmDistorted.SetInputConnection(wl.GetOutputPort());
        dsmDistorted.SetLookupTable(lut);
        dsmDistorted.SetScalarRange(sr[0]+20, sr[1]);

        vtkActor dsDistortedActor = vtkActor.New();
        dsDistortedActor.SetMapper(dsmDistorted);

        m_renDistorted.AddActor(dsDistortedActor);
        m_renWin.SetDesiredUpdateRate(0);
        m_renWin.Render();
        m_renDistorted.ResetCamera();
```

So, basically, I am creating a terrain representation using polygons, passing it through the warplens, passing that through a dataset mapper to give it pretty colors, then displaying it.

The issue is that the "warp" appears to be static to the terrain, not to the camera. I'm pretty new to VTK, so it's possible that I don't understand how the Interactor and the Camera are related.

Can someone help?